# eager loading the first record of an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a very simple forum made from Rails app, I get 30 topics from the database in the index action like this

```
def index

@topics = Topic.all.page(params[:page]).per_page(30)

end
```

However, when I list them in the views/topics/index.html.erb, I also want to have access to the first post in each topic to display in a tooltip, so that when users scroll over, they can read the first post without having to click on the link. Therefore, in the link to each post in the index, I add the following to a data attribute

```
topic.posts.first.body
```

each of the links looks like this

```
<%= link_to simple_format(topic.name), posts_path(
:topic_id => topic), :data => { :toggle => 'tooltip', :placement => 'top', :'original-title' => "#{ topic.posts.first.body }"}, :class => 'tool' %>
```

While this works fine, I'm worried that it's an n+1 query, namely that if there's 30 topics, it's doing this 30 times

```
 User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."topic_id" = $1 ORDER BY "posts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["topic_id", 7]]
```

I've noticed that Rails does automatic caching on some of these, but I think there might be a way to write the index action differently to avoid some of this n+1 problem but I can figure out how. I found out that I can

```
include(:posts)
```

to eager load the posts, like this

```
@topics = Topic.all.page(params[:page]).per_page(30).includes(:posts)
```

However, if I know that I only want the first post for each topic, is there a way to specify that? if a topic had 30 posts, I don't want to eager load all of them.

I tried to do

```
.includes(:posts).first
```

but it broke the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work for me, so give this a shot and see if it works for you:

```
Topic.includes(:posts).where("posts.id = (select id from posts where posts.topic_id = topics.id limit 1)").references(:posts)
```

This will create a **dependent subquery** in which the `posts` topic_id in the subquery is matched up with the `topics` id in the parent query. With the `limit 1` clause in the subquery, the result is that each `Topic` row will contain only 1 matching `Post` row, eager loaded thanks to the `includes(:post)`.

Note that when passing an SQL string to `.where`, that references an eager loaded relation, the `references` method should be appended to inform ActiveRecord that we're referencing an association, so that it knows to perform appropriate joins in the subsequent query. Apparently it technically works without that method, but you get a deprecation warning, so you might as well throw it in lest you encounter problems in future Rails updates.

Comment: But the query quantities is not reduced, instead they go inside a big query :) By the way, as I remember `select` in `where` is not a good style in SQL.

Comment: @BillyChan Give it a try, it most certainly reduces the query count. Down from 30 to 1, it should be. You're right it does go in to one "larger" query, which is (unless I've misunderstood) what the OP wanted; to eliminate the additional query performed by doing `topic.posts.first`. Also, I'm not quite sure why a `select` would not be a good style in the `where` clause, as I'm not sure how you would perform a subquery (or indeed any query) without it. Maybe I've misunderstood you though, can you elaborate?

Comment: Teeg, I forget where I read that claim and can't find reliable source at present. Anyway in this case I would prefer not use `includes` if it needs a long query to fix :)

Comment: @BillyChan Alright, fair enough, let me know if you find that article. If by "query" you mean the ruby/rails code, I don't believe its all that long, and its pretty easy to read (but to each their own). If you mean the SQL that is generated, yes  it is rather long, but that really doesn't matter. The size of the query makes no difference, what matters is proper indexing, and proper query structure which this, despite being "long", definitely is. I would even argue that a "long" query which improves performance, so long as it is still readable, should usually be preferred in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

There're a few issues when trying to solve this "natively" via Rails which are detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565472/rails-how-to-eager-load-limited-records-of-ordered-association-without-n1-quer).

We solved it with an SQL scope, for your case something like:

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :first_post, class_name: "Post", primary_key: :first_post_id, foreign_key: :id

  scope :with_first_post, lambda {
    select(
      "topics.*,
      (
        SELECT id as first_post_id
        FROM posts
        WHERE topic_id = topics.id
        ORDER BY id asc
        LIMIT 1
      )"
    )
  }
end

Topic.with_first_post.includes(:first_post)
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can't. Custom association is often used to allow conditions on includes except `limit`.

> If you eager load an association with a specified :limit option, it will be ignored, returning all the associated objects. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :most_recent_comments, -> { order('id DESC').limit(10) }, 
                                 class_name: 'Comment'
end

Picture.includes(:most_recent_comments).first.most_recent_comments 
# => returns all associated comments.
```